# Progress 4gl - Dutch Language Conversion to English

Tags: translation, progress-4gl, openedge

We are working on a product which is developed using progress 4gl but with Dutch naming conventions.

Source code has (naming convention, procedure description, on screen messages, table/fields/variable) all in Dutch language.  Could anyone suggest if there is some way to map the table/fields to their corresponding English names?

We have tried to google but we didn't reach to a fixed solutions. All suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For texts (labels, strings etc) Progress offers translation software.

Take a look at the documentation and if it seems good contact your Progress salesperson for a demo (the translation package is a separate license).

Linking to the 11.3 version of the documentation. If you need to look at another version search for it on [community.progress.com](http://community.progress.com)

[Visual Translator](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge112/pdfs/dvvis/dvvis.pdf)

[Translation Manager](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/pdfs/dvtmg/dvtmg.pdf)

The source code is a different thing. Perhaps you can COMPILE with the XREF and LISTING options - perhaps that will create output that you somehow can run through a translator (after some parsing).

```
COMPILE file.p [SAVE] 
    XREF xref-file.txt [STRING-XREF string-xref.txt] LISTING listing-file.txt.
```

You can also replace XREF with XML-XREF and a XML-file will be created instead of a flat text file.

Check in on documentation (link above) on formats for these files.